# How can I change controller in Codeigniter on the basis of number of parameters in URL

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I trying to change my controller but it doesn't work:

```
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(:any)'] = "/search/index/$2"; 

$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "/item/index/$2/$3/$4";
```

Is it possible? Or I should use the URI segments and then call my controller?

Comment: With my own php framework, I use .htaccess quickly

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way round (from more to less "detailed" routes):

```
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "/item/index/$2/$3/$4";
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(:any)'] = "/search/index/$2";
```